# HOW TO refresh the content of a single row in my ListView using OnItemClick

Tags: android, listview, checkbox, refresh, onitemclicklistener

I have a ListView with a CheckBox.
What I am trying to implement is an onItemClick (in my activity) that check/select my CheckBox if I click on the row, as you can see below:

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
        int position, long id) {
    MyItem row = ListofRows.get(position);
    row.setSelected(true);
    myAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

When I click in the row, the ListView is refreshed because of the method notifyDataSetChanged()

**THE PROBLEM IS**: this method refreshes the whole ListView and as a result, the ScroolBar goes to the beginning (the user is driven to the header of the list) even if the user is at the bottom of the list.

**WHAT I NEED IS**: Refresh just this single clicked row so the user won't be driven to the beginning of the list.

Are there any solutions to this problem?

Comment: see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724874/android-update-single-item-in-list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use the selected index
View v = getListView.getChildAt(index);

Now update the view with the new values.