# ListView Recycler deleting data

Tags: java, android, listview, android-edittext, recycle

I have a custom ListView with a few TextViews and EditTexts and i want to prevent the recycler from deleting the data when an item is scrolled out of view.  I looked at other posts but i havent found a solution. Please help.

Here is my code.

```
Java :


import android.text.Editable;
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;



public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private int[] fif={0,0,0,0,0,0},tw={0,0,0,0,0,0},scorePerm={0,0,0,0,0,0},scorePerm2=       {0,0,0,0,0,0};
    private int scoreTemp=0;`






private static final String TAG = CustomAdapter.class.getSimpleName();
ArrayList<DataModel> listArray;

public CustomAdapter() {
    listArray = new ArrayList<DataModel>(5);
    listArray.add(new DataModel("Player 1", 1 ));
    listArray.add(new DataModel("Player 2", 2));
    listArray.add(new DataModel("Player 3", 3));
    listArray.add(new DataModel("Player 4", 4));
    listArray.add(new DataModel("Player 5", 5));
    listArray.add(new DataModel("Player 6", 6));

}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listArray.size();    
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return listArray.get(i);    
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;                   
}

public int getViewTypeCount() {                 

    return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int index, View view, final ViewGroup parent) {

   if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
       view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, parent,false);

    }



    view.setClickable(true);
    view.setFocusable(true);
    view.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.menuitem_background);

    final DataModel dataModel = listArray.get(index);

    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.player_un);
    textView.setText(dataModel.getName());

    Button button0 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.plus50);

    Button button1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.minus50);

    Button button2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.plus20);

    Button button3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.minus20);

    Button ok = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.un_ad_ok);

    final Button reset = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.un_ad_res);

    final TextView score = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.score);
    score.setText(R.string.scorepoints);

    final EditText fifty = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.score50);
    fifty.setText(R.string.scorepoints);

    final EditText two = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.score20);
    two.setText(R.string.scorepoints);

    final EditText other = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.scoreplus);
    other.setText(R.string.scorepoints);



    //other code 



    return view;
}
}


ListView XML :

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Uno" >

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/scoreplus"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/plus20"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
     android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
     android:hint="@string/scorepoints"
     android:inputType="number" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/minus20"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/scoreplus"
     android:text="@string/minus" />

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/score20"
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/minus20"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/minus20"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/minus20"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:text="@string/scorepoints"
     android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
     android:textSize="12sp" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/plus20"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/score20"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/score20"
     android:text="@string/plus" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/Image20"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/score20"
     android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/plus20"
     android:contentDescription="@string/player"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/minus50"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/score20"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/score50"
     android:text="@string/minus" />

 <EditText
     android:id="@+id/score50"
     android:layout_width="40dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/minus50"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/minus50"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/plus50"
     android:inputType="number"
     android:text="@string/scorepoints"
     android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
     android:textSize="12sp" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/plus50"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="30dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignTop="@+id/score50"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Image50"
     android:text="@string/plus" />

 <ImageView
     android:id="@+id/Image50"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/plus50"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:contentDescription="@string/player"
     android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/score"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/scoreplus"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/scoreplus"
     android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/score50"
     android:text="@string/scorepoints"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <TextView
     android:id="@+id/player_un"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/score"
     android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/score"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:text="@string/player"
     android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/un_ad_ok"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/minus50"
     android:layout_below="@+id/score50"
     android:text="@string/ok" />

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/un_ad_res"
     style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
     android:layout_width="50dp"
     android:layout_height="40dp"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/Image20"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:layout_below="@+id/minus20"
     android:enabled="false"
     android:text="@string/cancel" />
```

Comment: [Android Adapter Good Practices](http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you didn't implement the listview's adapter as you should.

please watch "[the world of listView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CDUQFjAB&url=http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html&ei=KxLjUfGyHseqtAbBmYHYBA&usg=AFQjCNFRUicJ-KxHewtNPlf_4W-hV0bbEQ)" and maybe read the [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17629630/878126) in order to know how to handle viewHolders.

if you wish to save the text in the editText, you should either update the data as soon as the text is changed, or when the user touches the listView (which is a bit harder).

the reason you get this "bug" is that listView re-uses old views that were scrolled outside of it, so you need to store the lost data somewhere , and always update the views to the correct data.

Comment: I really like the recycling mechanism to save the ram. +1 for you.

Comment: @Eng.Fouad when implemented well, you can also make it very fast and smooth. also , if there is internet connection involved, you can use the Volley library as shown recently on google IO 2013: https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/325304728

Comment: Impressive! Where can I find Volley library?

Comment: as this website says: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/ ,  use the command "git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley"