# How to Update single galleryview children?

Tags: android

How to call notifyDataSetChanged() for only one element of gallery? Default call update evrything, which is quite resourse expencieve and unnecessary. I want solution, which works fro API 8.

Comment: What adapter base class are you using?

Comment: I am extending baseadapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do that you need to find the row view that you want to refresh and make the refresh manually. Something like this:

```
private void updateSingleView(int i) {

    View viewToUpdate = listview.getChildAt(i - listview.getFirstVisiblePosition());
    //Do whatever update you need to do
    viewToUpdate.invalidate(); //Or postInvalidate() if you call it from a non Ui thread.
}
```

Found by this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724874/how-can-i-update-a-single-row-in-a-listview?rq=1).

Comment: I have a problem. It does not work for galleryview.

Comment: @user1551603 I suggest you move from `Gallery` to `ViewPager` since it is depracated from API 16 and up. You can use the android compatibility library to use the `ViewPager` in API 8 that you need. Link: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Gallery.html

Comment: i just dont want to rebuild quite big infrastacture:)

Comment: @user1551603 You are right it requires quite a lot changes in your code but this way you futureproof your app and also I do not think what you ask is possible in Gallery (at least i do not know a way of achieving this to be frank:) ).