# Is possible refresh a item from a ListView without refresh entire list?

Tags: android, performance, android-listview

I have a listview with many items(10 - 200 approx.), when I click on an item, I update its attributes and then update the listview. But as many items the update is a bit slow.
Is there anyway to only update an item in a listview without having to refresh the entire list?

Regards

Comment: What constitutes an "update"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to change an element of a ListView, but it is not a good solution, because you are accessing a widget of your listview item directly e.g. textview. But it at least can be used as a temporary solution

Example:

[How can I update a single row in a ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724874/how-can-i-update-a-single-row-in-a-listview)