# How to Add item to GridView dynamically on Android without notifyDataSetChanged?

Tags: android, gridview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a gridview with custom adapter.
it's added photo from background service by notifyDataSetChanged of adapter method.
but its method re-created all items. the items took many times to create.
the reason why items is part of a photo.

So, i want to add dynamically item to add.

Comment: It is not possible to add View to GridView dynamically without calling notifyDataSetChanged().may be you need to design a custom View.

Comment: Can I use getVisibillity of view in getView() of adapter? if getVisibillity is visible , return convertView simply.

Comment: visibility also, you have to determine it in getView() method...

Comment: Hmm..Thank you for reply..
Then, what opensource library for this problem exists?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not clear if you want to add a new View or just refresh an old one. You can update a single view already in the GridView by calling getView() on it. [The accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724874/how-can-i-update-a-single-row-in-a-listview) has worked for me for ListView, I'm sure it will be similar for GridView.

For no hassle loading of images I recommend [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

Comment: Thanks you svenoaks very much..
it works...awesome...