# open job details on click of list

Tags: android, listview

I have made an app in which i have an listView with JobCode and category.Now what i want to do is that when user click on a particular list item ,the full description on job should be displayed.But i dnt know hw to do it

Custom Adapter.Java

```
public class SearchJobsCustomList extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {
    Context c;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;

    HashMap<String, String> resultp = new HashMap<String, String> ();
//    ArrayList<SearchValues> values;
//    SearchValues a;

    public SearchJobsCustomList(Context c, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data) {
        super ();
        this.c = c;
        this.data = data;


    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return data.size ();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {


        if (view == null) {
            view = LayoutInflater.from (c).inflate (R.layout.custom_search_jobs_lists, viewGroup, false);
            resultp = data.get (i);
            TextView JobCode = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_job_code);
            TextView Category = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_category);
            TextView ExpYrs = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_yrs);
            TextView ExpMnths = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_exp_mnths);
            TextView Date = (TextView) view.findViewById (R.id.tv_date);
            Button bestCandidate = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.bt_best_candidates);
            Button appliedJobs = (Button) view.findViewById (R.id.bt_applied_jobs);

            if (resultp.get ("counts").equals (0)) {
                bestCandidate.setFocusable (false);
                bestCandidate.setText (0);

            } else {
                bestCandidate.setText (resultp.get ("counts"));
            }

            if (resultp.get ("applied").equals (0)) {
                appliedJobs.setFocusable (false);
                appliedJobs.setText (0);

            } else {
                appliedJobs.setText (resultp.get ("applied"));
            }


            JobCode.setText (resultp.get ("code"));
            Category.setText (resultp.get ("category"));
            ExpYrs.setText (resultp.get ("minExp"));
            ExpMnths.setText (resultp.get ("maxExp"));
            Date.setText (resultp.get ("postedOn"));

            view.setOnClickListener (this);


        }
        return view;
    }
```

SearchJobList.Java

```
public class SearchJobsList extends Activity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {


    private ListView lvresources;
    private Context c = this;
    SearchJobsCustomList searchJobsCustomList;


    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate (savedInstanceState);
        getWindow ().requestFeature (Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR);
        getActionBar ().hide ();
        setContentView (R.layout.search_job_lists);
        initialize ();

    }


    private void initialize() {

        lvresources = (ListView) findViewById (R.id.listView);
        searchJobsCustomList = new SearchJobsCustomList (c, SearchJobs.arraylist);

        lvresources.setAdapter (searchJobsCustomList);
        lvresources.setOnItemClickListener (this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {



    value = data.get (i);
    Intent intent = new Intent (c, JobsDescription.class);
    intent.putExtra ("code", value.get ("code"));
    intent.putExtra ("category", value.get ("category"));
    intent.putExtra ("position", value.get ("position"));
    intent.putExtra ("desc", value.get ("desc"));
    intent.putExtra ("type", value.get ("type"));
    intent.putExtra ("hours", value.get ("hours"));
    intent.putExtra ("status", value.get ("status"));
    intent.putExtra ("expiryDate", value.get ("expiryDate"));
    intent.putExtra ("address", value.get ("address"));
    intent.putExtra ("state", value.get ("state"));
    intent.putExtra ("country", value.get ("country"));
    intent.putExtra ("city", value.get ("city"));
    intent.putExtra ("gender", value.get ("gender"));
    intent.putExtra ("religion", value.get ("religion"));
    intent.putExtra ("summary", value.get ("summary"));
    startActivity (intent);
    }
}
```

The arraylist contains all the job details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to show the full job description in the same list or in a new activity?

**New activity:**

You are using `resultp = data.get(i)` to get the data. In the `adapter. onItemClick()` you can add the list position of the job to the intent using `intent.putExtra("myJobID", i)` and you can receive it when you start your job detail activity using [`getIntExtra`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getIntExtra%28java.lang.String,%20int%29). Then you can use that to search for the full job description like you search for the job details here. Or if the job description is just a string you can pass only that string. The context of your code will determine what is more appropriate.

**Same list:**
You can update the value of a list item as in this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3727813/2536178). Put this code in your `onItemClick(){}` block.

Comment: @Umar Saad  i m using different activity.see i edited my code but my list is not getting clicked

Comment: Try setting up the `onClickListener` in your `initialize()` function.

`lvresources.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) { Log.d("Item being clicked!", Integer.toString(i)); } } });` Use LogCat to see if the item is being clicked.

Comment: nw it is being clicked but nw i m getting 0 as the size of the data(which is the ArrayList)

Comment: Are you sure there is data in the list? In `initialize()` add `Log.d("Job list length", Integer.toString(SearchJobs.arraylist.length));` to see if the problem is with the list or with the adapter.