# Android : How to update a single row in a Recycler view list

Tags: android, arrays, json, listview, android-recyclerview

I have an app that calling an **API** its resulting around **500 rows** creation.In my app the row content can update in the detail page. So after update is there any possibility to update the row in the **Recycler View** without calling the **API** again.

**Activity**

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get("URL", new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {
@Override
 public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
try {                        
    String jsonStr = new String(responseBody, "UTF-8");
    if (jsonStr != null) {
    try {  
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
        JSONObject cStatus = jsonArray.getJSONObject(jsonArray.length()-1);
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) 
        {
        JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
        String firstName = c.getString("firstName");
        String subDistributerId = c.getString("subDistributerId");
        SubdistributorItem item = new SubdistributorItem();
        item.setSubDistributorName(firstName);
        item.setSubDistributorId(subDistributerId);
        ubdistributorItemList.add(item);
        }
       } catch (JSONException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
       }
     } 
     Collections.sort(subdistributorItemList, new Comparator<SubdistributorItem>() {
     public int compare(SubdistributorItem o1, SubdistributorItem o2) {
     return o1.getSubDistributorName().compareToIgnoreCase(o2.getSubDistributorName());
    }
   });
    adapter = new SubdistributorRecyclerAdapter(getActivity(),subdistributorItemList);
     mRecyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
   }
  }               
});
```

**Adapter Class**

```
public class SubdistributorRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<SubdistributorListRowHolder>  {
private List<SubdistributorItem> subdistributorItems;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<SubdistributorItem> arraylist;

public SubdistributorRecyclerAdapter(Context context, List<SubdistributorItem> subdistributorItems) {
    this.subdistributorItems = subdistributorItems;
    this.mContext = context;
    this.arraylist = new ArrayList<SubdistributorItem>();
    this.arraylist.addAll(subdistributorItems);
}

@Override
public SubdistributorListRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup viewGroup,  int i) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.subdistributor_list_item, null);
    SubdistributorListRowHolder mh = new SubdistributorListRowHolder(v);

    layout_subdistributor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(final View v) {
      Intent i = new Intent(mContext, SubdistributorDetail.class);
                    Log.e("Tag shop ", "ShopKeeper Detail called");
                    i.putExtra("subDistributorStatus", txt_RechargeSubdistributor.getText().toString());
                    i.putExtra("subDistributorId", txt_subDistributorId.getText().toString());
                    mContext.startActivity(i);

        }
    });
    return mh;
}
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(SubdistributorListRowHolder subDistributorListRowHolder, int i) {

    SubdistributorItem subdistributorItem = subdistributorItems.get(i);
    Log.e("Tag ", "adapter "+ subdistributorItem.getSubDistributorName());

}
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != subdistributorItems ? subdistributorItems.size() : 0);
}
}
```

So can any one please help me to update a single row in a list without calling the API again.

Comment: See  here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724874/how-can-i-update-a-single-row-in-a-listview

Comment: you can use adapter.notifydatasetchanged in OnResume of your activity

Comment: how can i update the particular row item @Ragu Swaminathan

Comment: you are dynamically handling the list correct?

Comment: yes @Ragu Swaminathan

Comment: does the below answer works for you?

Comment: No, am not getting the position the I click the row in the view @Ragu Swaminathan

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104152/discussion-between-ragu-swaminathan-and-binil-s).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update item in your list `subdistributorItems`. Then call `adapter.notifyItemChanged(int position)`. You can get a position in ClickListener using

```
layout_subdistributor.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(final View v) {
        if (mh.getAdapterPosition() != RecyclerView.NO_POSITION) {
          int position = mh.getAdapterPosition();
          // edit your object by calling subdistributorItems.get(position)
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Try using this method, to update a single row.

```
notifyItemChanged(int position)
```

Comment: am not getting the position that is my problem @vishnu narayanan

Comment: in onCreateViewHolder() method i have a click listener there, can i get the positon that which row that i clicked @vishnu narayanan

Comment: Recycler view unlike listview does not have a onItemClicked method. There are many ways to do a custom implementation. Try this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24885223/why-doesnt-recyclerview-have-onitemclicklistener-and-how-recyclerview-is-dif

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
public static class SubdistributorListRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    private TextView textView_alphabet;
    private TextView textView_name;
    private TextView textView_tag;
    private ImageView imageViewUserImage;
    private ImageView imageViewMoreButton;
    private LinearLayout linearLayoutMainContent;

    public ViewHolder(View itemLayoutView) {
        super(itemLayoutView);
        textView_alphabet = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textView_alphabet);
        textView_name = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textView_name);
        textView_tag = (TextView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.textView_tag);
        imageViewUserImage = (ImageView) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewUserImage);
        linearLayoutMainContent = (LinearLayout) itemLayoutView.findViewById(R.id.linearLayoutMainContent);
    }
}

 @Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(SubdistributorListRowHolder subDistributorListRowHolder, int i) {

 SubdistributorItem subdistributorItem = subdistributorItems.get(i);
 Log.e("Tag ", "adapter "+ subdistributorItem.getSubDistributorName());
 subDistributorListRowHolder.itemLayoutView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.e("Tag ", "Position "+ i);
        }
    });
 }
```

**Over here itemLayoutView is the mail layout which is clickable**
Modify the SubdistributorListRowHolder like this put all your layout component and find view by id.

Comment: where should i get viewHolder @bumba

Answer (score 0):

```
getViewForPosition(int position)
```

Obtain a view initialized for the given position. This method should be used by RecyclerView.LayoutManager implementations to obtain views to represent data from an RecyclerView.Adapter.

The Recycler may reuse a scrap or detached view from a shared pool if one is available for the correct view type. If the adapter has not indicated that the data at the given position has changed, the Recycler will attempt to hand back a scrap view that was previously initialized for that data without rebinding.
[description here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Recycler.html#getViewForPosition(int))

Answer (score -1):

Its simple.
Make the changes in the ArrayList that is bonded with the recycler view and call notifyDataSetChanged() on the Recycler View.

Comment: out of 500 rows in the list, how can I update one row that view @Pradeet Swamy