# How to update a listview item via adapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

It's easy to `remove`, `add` and `insert` an item from the listview adapter object, but I don't think I see a direct method to `update` an item in the listview adapter. Obviously, I could simply replace via remove/add, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something obvious. 
Right now, I'm simply updating the underlying Item Array and refresh the entire listview by recreating/assigning the adapter (probably also not very elegant).
I hope the question is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ArrayList in adapter class for update In ArrayList there is method called `set()` which update the item in arraylist after updation call `notifyItemchanged()` which update an item in listview

Check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724874/how-can-i-update-a-single-row-in-a-listview)

Comment: yeah, it was more academic curiosity to see if it can be done via the adapter object, but I understand that this is used more for temporary things like filtering the shown results (instead of altering the underlying ArrayList)