# Update ListView row on click of Floating Action Button

Tags: android, listview, android-mediaplayer

I currently have a `Floating Action Buttons` that will record some speech when held down. Once the `Button` is released I would like a particular row on a `ListView` to show a play `Button`.

I have the index of the row in a variable named "selected". But I do not know how to make the `ImageButton` on that row visible from within the `FAB.OnClickListener`. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: see the accepted answer on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3724874/how-can-i-update-a-single-row-in-a-listview

Answer (score 0):

If you want only one item of your list view to show the play button put a variable `int playButtonPosition = -1` in your adapter.

In `getView` method of your adapter, check `if (position == playButtonPosition)` and show your button here.

In `FAB.OnClickListener` update `adapter.playButtonPosition = selected` and notify your adapter about the changes `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.