# Android: Change properties of a single item in ListView

Tags: android, listview

I have an app with a ListView with custom items in a ListFragment. Purpose of the app is a checklist with tasks that change background color and add a checkmark when they're selected.

Now when the task is selected it passes this info to the connected SQLite-db and reloads the adapter. With an if-statement it checks if the task is finished and if so it adds a checkmark and changes the background.
This all worked fine, but when I have more tasks than the screen can hold it jumps to the top when reloading the adapter, standard behavior.

I've been experimenting with the info found on this page: [Android: Is it possible to refresh just one item in a listview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953381/android-is-it-possible-to-refresh-just-one-item-in-a-listview)
And this info has been pretty helpful:

```
View v = listViewItems.getChildAt(position - 
        listViewItems.getFirstVisiblePosition());
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

My own implementation is this:

```
private void updateView(int index){
    View v = getListView().getChildAt(index -
            getListView().getFirstVisiblePosition());

    if(v == null)
        return;

    v.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.finished_bg));

    IconTextView itv = (IconTextView) v.findViewById(R.id.task_item_icontextview);
    itv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Here is where it gets tricky.

1: It changes background, really nice, but when I scroll up or down and the item leaves the screen and then re-enters the background is back to it's standard color.
How do I make sure that the color stays this way?

2: The checkmark doesn't show at all. Am I making wrong references? Is it even possible to change properties this way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I solved it!

I stopped using the updateView method and implemented the following code on the right places:

```
adapter.clear();
adapter.addAll(tasksList);
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Adapter being the name of my customized adapter and taskList being the ArrayList with the info that should be placed in my ListView-items.

I tried doing this earlier, but made a little error.

Answer (score 0):

1. use [selector](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html) for the item backgrounds on pressed, selected, focused etc
   follow this simple tutorial [here](http://www.michenux.net/android-listview-highlight-selected-item-387.html)
2. the checkmark is a checkbox? then add a Boolean value on the class, false as default, and set it true on list item click, or set is !boolean so it can dynamically change on each click (reverts true/false on each click). change the adapter, not the listview.
    on the adapter, check if that boolean is true, set that checbox to checked

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I couldn't find an option with selector to select an item and keep it selected, while also finishing other tasks. Could have experimented with accepting multiple selections, but I didn't think that would be the best way to do this.

The checkmark is an IconTextView (Iconify), not a checkbox.