# Can an individual item in the list of data in an ArrayAdapter request for refresh?

Tags: android, android-listview, arraylist, android-arrayadapter, baseadapter

I have an `ArrayAdapter` that is bound to an `ArrayList<MyClass>`

There is a lot of logic inside `MyClass` including changing certain properties of MyClass objects that require a refresh in view. Once such a change is detected inside MyClass object, I would like to call the associated `ArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

However, the items of MyClass don't automatically store a reference to the adapter, while the adapter stores a reference to the ArrayList. Is there an easy way to solve this problem?

Comment: In which situation the MyClass object will change...means when database updated or in any other situation...

Answer (score 0):

You can't reload a single row, but instead you can get the requested view and make changes on it directly by calling `yourListView.getChildAt(int VisiblePosition);` where the `visiblePostion` is the position in the `ListView` minus `yourListView.getFirstVisiblePosition()`.

Like this :

```
View v = listViewItems.getChildAt(position - 
        listViewItems.getFirstVisiblePosition());
v.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
```

Answer by [Driss Bounouar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2953381/android-is-it-possible-to-refresh-just-one-item-in-a-listview)

Answer (score 0):

Please create a arrayadapter and apply your change in single item