# Refresh httpget Data from server in listView

Tags: android, listview, refresh, server, http-get

I get some data via httpget in a AsyncTask. This data I put into a listview.
This works fine so far. But now I want to implement that I refresh some data that changed on the server. What I am doing right now is that I reload the whole list via httpget to get all the data again but with refreshed/changed data. But I want to refresh only the changed data of the database in the listview so it does not take so long. How could I achieve this? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please see the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15407402/1506118) and also this [one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21897663/1506118)

Comment: Thank you for the answer but how can I combined this with httpget?